# I am having trouble with declaration files in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, declaration, referenceerror, declaration-files

I'm trying to use the trace function in my TypeScript code, which has been declared in a `.d.ts` file as follows:

```
declare function trace(arg: string | number | boolean);
declare function trace(arg: { id: number; name: string });
```

However, when I try to use the `trace` function in my code in the file `index.ts` as follows:

```
trace("trace with string"); // calls the trace function with a string argument
trace(true); // calls the trace function with a boolean argument
trace(1); // calls the trace function with a number argument
trace({ id: 1, name: "test" }); // calls the trace function with an object argument
```

I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: trace is not defined
```

Can anyone help and tell me what I am doing wrong? The `declaration` option is enabled in `tsconfig.json` too.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

Here is the JS code in a JS file where the trace function is being declared

```
var ErrorHelper = (function () {
    return {
        containsErrors: function (response) {
            if (!response || !response.responseText)
                return false;

            var errorValue = response.responseText;

            if (String(errorValue.failure) === "true"
                || Boolean(errorValue.failure)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        },
        trace: function (msg) {
            var traceMessage = msg;
            if (msg.responseText) {
                traceMessage = msg.responseText.errorMessage;
            }
            console.log("[" + new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
                + "] " + traceMessage);
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Where do you define the actual function implementation?

Comment: Did you import the required Class which trace function has been declared.? It would be better if you can provide stack trace of the error.

Comment: I am learning this from a book but stuck here. The trace function was defined in a JS file earlier. I have added the additional JS code in the edits above.

Here is the GitHub [https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Mastering-TypeScript-Fourth-Edition/tree/main/ch07 for the book materials.

Comment: @UsamaAhmed The thing is you are trying to access "trace" function which was defined inside "ErrorHelper" without referencing "ErrorHelper". Please try like this "ErrorHelper.trace("trace with string");". You can see sample example in this link. https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Mastering-TypeScript-Fourth-Edition/blob/d4855c98c9b66f95b05482e168555fa23cc73dd9/ch07/jsFiles/ErrorHelperSample.js

Comment: @TharakaAnanda thank you, this worked! However, what would I need to do to make it work like it is stated here in this file -> https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Mastering-TypeScript-Fourth-Edition/blob/main/ch07/declaration_file_samples.ts

Answer (score 0):

To make your function visible to other classes, you should also export it in the d.ts file:

You can find the information here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html

```
declare function trace(arg: string | number | boolean);
declare function trace(arg: { id: number; name: string });
export = trace;
export as namespace trace;
```